# CircuitLab "simulate this circuit" bug

Tags: bug, circuitlab

In [my answer to a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/219338/11683), I included a CircuitLab circuit that can be simulated to demonstrate the principle being discussed.

When I edit the answer and the embedded schematic, everything works normally, including the simulation.

However, when I look at my completed answer and click on the "simulate this circuit" link right below it, I get sent to a generic CircuitLab sign-up page. I cannot find any way to actually run the simulation from there. The only way I can do it is to first go back into the SE answer editor.

So, my question is this: Is the "simulate this circuit" link broken for everyone, or is there something peculiar to my circumstances?

---

Addendum: As I suspected, it has something to do with the fact that I have a CircuitLab account. After I explicitly logged out of CircuitLab, the "simulate this circuit" from an SE page is now working for me.

This is definitely a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I just clicked the "simulate" and was directed to a working copy of the simulator.  However, upon occasion, I too have experienced what you are questioning.  It seems inconsistent in re-directing, but thankfully not too often.

Comment: This happened to me the last time I tried to include a simulation in an answer.

Comment: I just clicked on your now deleted answer and got the same sign-up message.

Comment: I get the sign-up screen every time I click "simulate"

Comment: Does this have something to do with Circuit Lab's paywall?

Comment: @MattYoung: Yes, but my understanding is that SE and CL have a relationship in which SE users should not encounter it. I'm wondering whether the fact that I have a CL account has something to do with what I'm seeing.

Comment: I just had the same problem, but it seems deleting the cookies for circuitlab helps!